# Does macOS 11 Big Sur support FireWire?

Tags: macos, hardware, big-sur, driver, firewire

I'm attempting to use legacy FireWire hardware peripherals in macOS 11 Big Sur.

Apple has provided an OEM hardware dongle connectivity path that is confirmed working in macOS Catalina:

1. [Apple Thunderbolt to FireWire Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD464LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter)
2. [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter)

Unfortunately, the one piece of FireWire hardware that I'm trying to use [does not appear to work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412516/external-isight-camera-with-m1-mac) in Big Sur (on an M1 Mac).

Various threads online seem to indicate that FireWire products are either not supported in Big Sur or have various incompatibility issues.

- [Oh, Firewire UA products are incompatible with Big Sur!!](https://uadforum.com/macos-11-big-sur-mac-m1-sub-forum/51675-oh-firewire-ua-products-incompatible-big-sur.html)

To confirm: was FireWire support dropped in Big Sur, on Intel and/or Apple Silicon?

Was there an Apple announcement of this change?

Do any of your FireWire peripherals work in Big Sur? Has anyone tested a FireWire device and found it to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireWire support, in general, has **not** been removed from macOS Big Sur or Apple Silicon.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5ISyI3VcWo) demonstrates daisy-chaining 3 FireWire peripherals to an M1 MacBook Pro running macOS 11 Big Sur:

- FireWire Hard Disk
- FireWire Audio Interface
- FireWire Video Camera

> So all-in-all I'm really surprised all this equipment still works, or at least it works the same way as it did in the previous versions of Macs with Intel processors.
>
> I honestly expected Apple would have dropped FireWire support on these newer Macs but, surprisingly, it's still possible as long as you have the right adapters.
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5ISyI3VcWo

[image: FireWire M1]

Answer (score -1):

My Motu 828 mk2 firewire interface doesn't work with Big Sur. This was confirmed by Motu's technical support. This is my experience !

Comment: That sounds more like compatibility issue with that audio interface, not the firewire itself.