# How to update external iSight firmware?

Tags: macos, webcam, firewire, accessories

Apple released several firmware revisions for the external iSight camera:

- iSight 1.0.3 Update

  - Improved audio performance
- iSight 1.0.2 Update

  - Improved auto exposure
  - Improved auto white balance
  - Enhanced IIDC compliance
  - Better overall performance

How can I update my iSight to the latest firmware revision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple released an iSight Updater software package, which is still available online:

> #### iSight Updater 1.0.3
>
> https://support.apple.com/kb/DL502

The problem is that the software download requires Mac OS X `v10.3` Panther to run.

iSight can also be updated on OS X `10.4` Tiger and `10.5` Leopard. The updater on those systems is located at:

`\System\Library\CoreServices\iSight Updaters\iSight Updater`

So, find an OS X `10.3`, `10.4`, or `10.5` machine (or VM?) to run the iSight Updater software.